# Chunk upload does not work with large files - Laravel 5.8

Tags: ajax, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone, laravel-5.8

I need to upload large files to my site, and to do this, I used the **Dropzone JS**, with [pion/laravel-chunk-upload](https://packagist.org/packages/pion/laravel-chunk-upload), I do not understand, everything is good and true, but although this, any upload for large files is not completed, when uploading small files, I get a result, but When I try with larger files eg 5MB,

- **It stops at a part of uploading** for Hosts eg (Hostinger)
- does **not work** and gives **an error from laravel *validator*** for WampServer 4 (localhost)

> I tried here to remove my Validator, but the same problem, I can't
>   upload or check if is a valid file or something like that! (for localhost)

I tried a lot but I do not understand the problem and can't find a solution, please help, this is my code:

**My view:**

```
<form action="{{ route('files') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="fileupload" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ $item->id }}">
      <div class="fallback">
           <input name="file" type="files" multiple />
      </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
// UPLOAD FILES 
    protected function uploadFiles(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'file' => 'required|max:3145730', // 3GB
            'item_id' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        $item_id = $request->item_id;
        $item_data = Item::whereId($item_id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->whereStatus(0)->first();

        if (!$item_data || $validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'error' => 'Invalid data!'
            ], 401); 
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) { 
            # CHECK IF IS FILE
            if ($request->file('file')->isValid()) {
                $file = $request->file('file');
                # UPLOAD
                $type = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                $mime = $file->getMimeType();
                $size = $file->getSize();
                $width = null;
                $height = null;

                if (!in_array($type, ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'zip']) || !in_array($mime, ['application/octet-stream', 'application/zip', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'])) {
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => true,
                        'error' => 'You can\'t upload files of this type.'
                    ], 401); 
                }

                // create the file receiver
                $receiver = new FileReceiver("file", $request, HandlerFactory::classFromRequest($request));
                // check if the upload is success, throw exception or return response you need
                if ($receiver->isUploaded() === false) {
                    throw new UploadMissingFileException();
                }
                // receive the file
                $save = $receiver->receive();
                // check if the upload has finished (in chunk mode it will send smaller files)
                if ($save->isFinished()) {
                    // save the file and return any response you need, current example uses `move` function. If you are
                    // not using move, you need to manually delete the file by unlink($save->getFile()->getPathname())
                    if (in_array($type, ['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg'])) {
                        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
                    }
                    return $this->saveFile($save->getFile(), $item_id, $type, $mime, $size, $width, $height);
                }
                // we are in chunk mode, lets send the current progress
                /** @var AbstractHandler $handler */
                $handler = $save->handler();
                return response()->json([
                    "done" => $handler->getPercentageDone(),
                    'status' => true
                ]);
            }
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'error' => 'Invalid data! Please upload a valid file.'
        ], 401); 
    }
```

**JS:**

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "DRAG & DROP FILES HERE TO UPLOAD";
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileupload", {
    acceptedFiles: ".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .zip",
    chunking: true,
    method: "POST",
    maxFilesize: 3072, // 3GB
    chunkSize: 10000000, // 10MB
    maxFiles: 6,
    parallelChunkUploads: true,
});
```

Comment: `maxFilesize:` stands for mb not kb right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your PHP.ini configuration for max size.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 11M
```

Comment: but it's work with localhost, not in my host, I see when I upload, It stop :(